# Can I pray while seeing blood spots due to high prolactin hormones?

Tags: salat, fiqh, women

My Prolactin hormone in high and I see some blood spot these days.

The question is this that now with this bleeding can I pray or not?

And if your answer is yes should I do any special thing like baptism or something else?

---

**Extra details**

The bleeding is irregular, some days it shows, but some days I see nothing.  It's also not part of my period — I first noticed it two weeks before my period started — although it does seem to have affected it.

I have been to a doctor in attempt to control it, but the problem persists even while on medication.

Comment: I would like to help BUT I don't any knowledge about the medical state you describe so any answer would be speculative... perhaps you can describe a bit more: is this state something you can avoid or reduce by any measure ? is this state something chronical and/or influenced by outside factors (wheather / stress etc.) ?

Comment: Thank you very much @Yahia .Doctor gave me some pills but they have not removed the problem completely yet.Bleeding is not regular.Some days I may see no blood.My problem has disassembled my period.And I should say stress is the most important reason of it.Now in days that I dont see blood I pray and when I see blood I wont.I dont know what should I do...

Comment: Thank for the information... the main point to consider is this: does the blood constitute part of "period-related bleeding" or is it considered being "non-period-related" ? Depending on this determination one can try to give an answer - I suspect this determination needs to be founded on some medical knowledge (like you doctor).

Comment: No.It is completely irrelative from my period.I say this from the date of my period time.It begins from 16th of the month and I saw blood in the first of the month.It can be related to my period bleeding.

Comment: You confuse me: you write "completely irrelative from my period" and "it can be related to my period bleeding"... perhaps I misunderstand but I think that this contradicts each other...

Comment: No.I didnt say its relative to my period.I said it has disarranged my period my its not relative to it.As a matter of fact it has disarranged all of my life.

Comment: IF your doctor says that the blood you see is related to your period-bleeding (although your period is disarranged) THEN you should not pray (but you can and should make Dua). IF it is not related THEN you can pray but should follow the existing ruling for cases of "not being able to hold urine"... Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask this question from someone that had enough knowledge and she said that you can pray IF the blood is not related to your period bleeding.